# Exercise 2.1 in Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I have a question about the following exercise in Serre's book. It's in the chapter 2.1 which revolves around the character of a representation.

The exercise goes as follows:

Let $\chi$ and $\chi'$ be the characters of two representations. Prove the formulas:
\begin{align*}
(\chi + \chi')^2_\sigma &= \chi^2 _\sigma + \chi'^2_\sigma + \chi \chi' \\
(\chi + \chi')^2_\alpha &= \chi^2 _\alpha + \chi'^2_\alpha + \chi \chi' \\
\end{align*}

Im still stuck on the first one. This is what I have done so far:

Since im unsure with the Elements on which the compositions of the character functions operate please feel free to correct me if I get something wrong with that. Let $s \in G$ and suppose that the two representations are representations of $G$. Further let $I$ be the Index Set of the Eigenvalues (with multiples) of $p_s$ and $J$ analogously for $p'_s$ (so that $\chi(s) = \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i$ and $\chi'(s) = \sum_{i \in I'} \lambda_i'$):

Now by definition (not sure whether I apply the definition correctly here):

\begin{align*}
(\chi + \chi')^2 _\sigma (s)  &= \sum_{i,h \in I, j,k \in J, i \leq h , j \leq k} (\lambda_i + \lambda_j')(\lambda_h + \lambda_k') \\
                              &= \sum_{i,h \in I, j,k \in J, i \leq h , j \leq k} \lambda_i \lambda_h + \lambda_i \lambda_k' + \lambda_j' \lambda_h + \lambda_j' \lambda_k'
\end{align*}

And similarly:

\begin{align*}
(\chi_{\sigma} ^{2} + \chi _{\sigma} ^{2} {'} + \chi \chi')(s) &= \sum_{i,h \in I, i \leq h} \lambda_i \lambda_h + \sum_{j,k \in J, j \leq k} \lambda_j ' \lambda_k ' + \sum_{i \in I, j \in J} \lambda_i \lambda_j '
\end{align*}

Now in the first equation one can see that for example there should be $|J|$ of each Eigenvalue of $p_s$ squared and $|I|$ of each Eigenvalue of $p'_s$ suqared in the sum which is where I get a problem showing the equation since in the second equation one can see that the each Eigenvalue of $p_s$ (and $p'_s$) only appears once squared as a summand.

Where am I getting something wrong and is this even the right method of solving the exercise?

Thank you in advance

Edit:
I have since seen that there is already a question about this equation on Stackexchange, [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308680/basic-identity-of-characters?rq=1)

Comment: You are indeed not applying the definition correctly. I think it's much easier to reason in terms of spaces than directly on the characters for this question, but if you prefer you can also use the formula in Proposition 3 just above the exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much that method seems way easier, I am going to answer my own question with your suggestion. Would you however mind explaining how one would apply the formula with the Eigenvalues correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Captain Lama my approach is quite complicated. Instead one could use the Proposition 3 (and not the formulas used in the proof of said proposition which I tried above).

With this one gets:

Let $s \in G$ and suppose that the two representations are representations of G.
With this we get:
\begin{align*}
(\chi + \chi')^2 _\sigma (s) &= \frac{1}{2} ((\chi+\chi')(s))^2 + (\chi+\chi')(s^2))\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\chi(s)^2 + 2(\chi \chi')(s) + \chi'(s)^2 + \chi(s^2) + \chi'(s^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\chi(s)^2 + \chi(s^2)) + \frac{1}{2}(\chi'(s)^2 + \chi'(s^2)) + (\chi \chi')(s) \\
&= \chi_\sigma ^2 (s) + \chi{'} _\sigma ^2(s) + (\chi \chi')(s) \\
&= (\chi_\sigma ^2 + \chi{'} _\sigma ^2+ \chi \chi')(s)
\end{align*}

Since the $s \in G$ was chosen freely the equality is shown.